# How to disable scrollback in webkit OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, webkit, osx-lion

I was wondering if there was a way to disable that awful scrollback that both Chrome and Safari now allow in Lion from Javascript or HTML. If scrollback isn't the right word, here's a pictures:

[image: That fabric coated nonsense]

I haven't heard many complain about it yet, but in my opinion it can hurt a design when it can't be controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable overflow on the html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html {
        overflow:hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```